# One-liner Algorithm to Combine Arrays into Arrays of All Possible Value Combinations?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Not quite sure I have the question fully formed, but what I'm trying to do is basically this:

```
# where the indices correspond to attributes fore example:
# [type, status]
x = %w(a b)
y = %w(c d)
combine(x, y) #=> [["a", "b"], ["a", "d"], ["c", "a"], ["c", "b"]]
```

The order of the array is always the same, so the reverse of each, such as `[b, a]`, are not included in the result.

What is this called and what's an efficient way to implement this?

I see [Array#permutation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000288), but that's not quite it...

This would hopefully work for any number of arrays and values: `combine(*arrays)`

Thanks!

**Update**

Here's a better example of what I'm looking for:

This `(x | y).combination(x.length).to_a` produces the following:

```
x = ["front_door", "open"]
y = ["back_door", "closed"]
(x | y).combination(x.length).to_a
=> [["front_door", "open"], ["front_door", "back_door"], ["front_door", "closed"], ["open", "back_door"], ["open", "closed"], ["back_door", "closed"]]
```

The actual result I'm looking for is this:

```
=> [["front_door", "open"], ["front_door", "closed"], ["back_door", "open"], ["back_door", "closed"]]
```

Or if it were a longer array:

```
x = ["house", "front_door", "open"]
y = ["building", "back_door", "closed"]
compute(x, y)
=> ["house", "front_door", "open"], ["house", "back_door", "open"], ["house", "front_door", "closed"], ["house", "back_door", "closed"], ["building", "front_door", "open"], ["building", "back_door", "open"], ["building", "front_door", "closed"], ["building", "back_door", "closed"]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I guess in the first example ["c", "a"] should look ["c", "d"]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x.zip(y).reduce(:product).map(&:flatten)
```

And for several arrays:

```
x.zip(y,z,w).reduce(:product).map(&:flatten)
```

Comment: what if the arrays were instead organized like this: `["house", "building"]`, `["front_door", "back_door"]`, `["open", "closed"]`, how would you get the same result?

Comment: @vlatropos [["house", "building"], ["front_door", "back_door"], ["open", "closed"]].reduce(:product).map(&:flatten). (The zip in the answer transforms the original representation into this one.)

Answer (score 3):

```
(x | y ).combination(x.length).to_a
```

Comment: this is really cool, but I guess my question wasn't quite right... updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def combine(*arrays)
  head, *tail = arrays.transpose
  head.product(*tail)
end

combine(x, y)
combine(x, y, z, ...)
```

*Side note digression:* this is one of the scenarios in which you get the point that functional languages make about functions being the *important stuff*. The fact that you have to call an object's method in OOP forces you -in this case- to contrivedly get their head/tail. When you have `product` as a function, for example in Python, you don't have this kind of problems:

```
itertools.product(*zip(*arrays))
```

Comment: Doesn't `x.zip(y).reduce(:product)` do the same thing as your Python example?

Comment: @Mark Thomas. The zip+reduce generates an extra level of nesting (that's why adamax's solution has to flatten afterwards). Moreover, it's very inefficient, Array#product supports arbitrary number of arguments, why don't use it instead of reducing/injecting?

Comment: But my point was that conceptually these kind of operations do not fit nicely into the OOP paradigm. You see this also when transposing; in Python you simply write "zip(*list_of_lists)" but in Ruby they had to create Array#transpose (otherwise you'd have to manually get its head/tail, like I did above: head, *tail = array_of_arrays; head.zip(*tail), and be careful that head is not nil!). That's because conceptually the zip operation takes a group of arrays, not an an array zipped with-the-rest-of-arrays. Hey, that's not a rant, I love Ruby!, just a digression, like I said :-)